# Error al instalar pngquant-bin@5.0.2 en NPM

Tags: nodejs, npm

estoy tratando de crear un nuevo proyecto de gatsby pero cuando intento hacerlo ocurre el siguiente error:

```
> node lib/install.js

  ‼ spawn UNKNOWN
  ‼ pngquant pre-build test failed
  i compiling from source
  × Error: pngquant failed to build, make sure that libpng-dev is installed
    at C:\Users\Jorge Luis Duran\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pngquant-bin\node_modules\bin-build\node_modules\execa\index.js:231:11
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! pngquant-bin@5.0.2 postinstall: `node lib/install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the pngquant-bin@5.0.2 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Jorge Luis Duran\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-13T14_24_39_877Z-debug.log
```

yo pienso que es libpng-dev el problema pero he estado buscando y creo que es porque no esta para windows

---resultado esperado--

Que se instale correctamente el paquete

Ya he intentado este comando pero no funciona por lo menos para mi
`npm install --save-dev pngquant --msvs_version=2013`

pero simplemete ocurre el mismo problema

Answer (score 0):

Intenta ejecutar primero:

```
npm install pngquant-bin@5.0.2
```

Luego intenta realizar la instalación.